# Besides player speed, what effects movement speed?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

My squire is unbearably slow running around, even with more player speed stat than a friend's monk I am not able to keep up. On my monk, huntress, or apprentice I feel just fine. Is the squire slow, or is there something else going on perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different characters have different base speeds. You can temporarily increase your speed with Blood Rage, but as far as speed goes, you are at a permanent disadvantage compared to the other classes.

Comment: which is totally made up for by the utter insanity of a map full of Slice n' Dice towers...